# Regex to search and replace a character in a C# string

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I'm trying to search for a comma in a string, and then "delete" it (replaced it with "", I'm assuming). I'm interested in a general way to do this. Does regex have a Replace method?

Comment: Regex does indeed have a Replace. Try to explain e x a c t l y  what you are trying to accomplish. For example also add Input / expected output.

Comment: Why just not use `String.Replace(",","")`.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just normal string.Replace()?

```
var result = str.Replace(",", string.Empty);
```

Comment: This sounds good - so if there's not a comma in there, nothing will happen??

Comment: THe string contains the price of something, so 1,200. I'm just trying to remove the comma from it!

Comment: @OhMisterRabbit that's correct. if there's no comma, the returned string would be unaltered.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use regular expression, try this

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\,");
        Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace("sample, text", string.Empty));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```